# How do I keep the cell blank when the formula outputs nothing, so that the text from the previous adjacent cell can overflow in it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting, cells, blank, if

I have a basic Excel `IF` function that shows a computation result if the condition is `TRUE`.
What I am trying to figure out how is, in case the condition is `FALSE`, how to keep the cell blank so that text from the previous, adjacent cell can freely overflow into it.

The formula is not on every row, for the simplicity of this question let's say it is on every other. So I will enter my formula into the top-most cell and drag it down all the way across the list. The `IF` function takes care of actually showing the computation result only in the cells I want it to show (i.e. in every other row, in this case).

However, on the rows where it is supposed to do nothing (and keep the overflowing text from the adjacent cell visible), it still overrides the overflowing text with its (empty) output. Even if I set it to output `""`, it will print an empty string and hide whatever text there was overflowing from the adjacent cell.

How do I actually tell the function to treat the cell as empty for all the practical purposes, even though there will be an invisible function in the background?

Here it is in pictures.

The basic structure:

[image: The basic structure]

What it does:

[image: What it does]

What I want it to do:

[image: What I want it to do]

I know of a workaround - drag down the current formula, then set a filter, select blanks and delete them. But I am looking for a simpler, more "proper", one-step solution, that can be executed right in the formula itself.

Neither wrapping the text in column `A`, nor making column `A` wider are acceptable, because the document will be printed out on a paper, so the formatting needs to be retained as is.
(This is not my document, I was asked to automate the computation, so the formatting is not up to me, it just needs to stay like this.)

Comment: Tell me one thing from **where you are getting that LONG Text**,,or are FIXED/COMMON Text, like A1 has Text Result and are in every Odd cells B1 has result are also in odd cells ,,, what formula you have applied to get 1,2,, and others !!  EVEN cells are looks like MERGED cells?

Comment: I don't think you can do it within the formula.  The cell has to actually be blank (empty) in order for Excel to overflow text from the adjacent cell.  Suggest you automate your filtering solution with a VBA macro if the manual steps are onerous.